# On license process on Arxiv

Tags: publications, legal-issues

Suppose I have published my inventions (written in papers) in arxiv. Can any information stated in papers be stolen? Is there any license process in arxiv? I want to know what is this license process in arxiv. Can my inventions be preserved by the license?

Comment: What do you mean by "inventions"? Patentable "devices"? Or just ideas and research results?

Comment: I think the main point of the license is to legally allow the arXiv to distribute your information. I doubt Cornell hire lawyers to prevent others from stealing your work...

Comment: New ideas in physics.

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/help/license for information about normal academic works. For patentable things, patent law applies. And patent law has changed recently.

Comment: If you do not want to distribute your work, ArXiv is not for you.  Also, you do not deserve to be on ArXiv.

Answer (score 1):

If you publish normal papers on arXiv (or pretty much anywhere), people would be plagiarizing if they copy it and present it as their own. You can retain most of the copyright, other than a license to arXiv to distribute what you post or you can give a [broad license](https://arxiv.org/help/license). But "stealing" your ideas, in the sense of decoupling your name from them is no longer ethical.

However, others can "use" your ideas and extend them. You don't "own" ideas because you hold copyright to the expression of them. In particular, if you present incomplete ideas in a publication, others can complete and extend them. In that regard arXiv is no different from any other "publication venue".

---

Patents are different. There was a time when the "inventor" of a device had more rights then currently (US law). But a change was made to permit patentability by the "first filer" rather than (necessarily) the inventor. (Note that this is a naive explanation.) So, it is probably necessary to hold patentable material close until you are ready to file.